# 'Three layers' and Three layered'

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

> This is a three layered mask.
> This is a three layers mask.

I have seen **three layered masks** and **Three layers masks**. Colloquially, I assume majority will assume both to be the same. Grammatically, are they use interchangeably?

Answer (score 0):

> layered; adjective (IN LAYERS); used to describe something that is complicated and interesting because it has many different levels or features:

> layer; noun [C] (MATERIAL); a level of material, such as a type of rock or gas, that is different from the material above or below it, or a thin sheet of a substance:

Therefore the ***three layered masks*** is the correct use however I would suggest *Three layer masks* would be the more commonly used wording. *Things are generally referred to as being in layers.*

As for interchangeability as the incorrect version is more commonly used, then I suppose yes.

> Sediments and sedimentary rocks are characterized by bedding, which occurs when layers of sediment, with different particle sizes are deposited on top of each other.

> Blending and layering paint on furniture can be achieved in a few different ways. The great thing is that there really is no right or wrong way when it comes to painting furniture.